# How can I download R package APE

Tags: r

I am using this code to download ape on R version 3.6.0:

```
install.packages("ape", dependencies = T)
```

and I am finding the following errors:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0'
> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
> ld: library not found for -lgfortran
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> make: *** [ape.so] Error 1
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ape’

I have attempted to download using the terminal too and this has also failed. I have checked the R version and APE is compatible with Rv3.6. Any ideas why this package cannot be downloaded?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to install the "source" version of the package, which requires compilation, and you are missing the required libraries. If you are on a Mac, you should install "command line tools for Xcode" to install from source. Otherwise, if prompted to install from source say "No", or use the "type = binary" argument to `install.packages`, to avoid source installation altogether.

Comment: Thanks! I tried installing Xcode on the Mac terminal but this didn't fix the problem. Do you mean to type the code like so: install.packages("ape", dependencies = T)? I attempted this but I received this error: Error in install.packages : object 'binary' not found

Answer (score -2):

check your R version, because i intalled 1 min ago and i'm not have problem.

[image]

Comment: I have 4.2.1 Version

Comment: I have checked my R version which is 3.6.0 but it is compatible with this package

Comment: therefore, my version is 4.2.1.

Try to install or update your version

Comment: I don't think R version is the issue here. The error message indicates that they are installing from source and missing required libraries.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).